# How do I re-create the warm film-like look of this 2012 Southern Comfort advert?

Tags: post-processing, color, warmth

Nobody's quite sure why the new Southern Comfort ad is quite as cool as it is, but I really like the warm '70s film-like look that they have added to the video.

How would I re-create this warmth in a photo? Is this the result of lens filters or post processing?

(I shoot RAW on a D800, if that matters)

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you think the warm look is film-like.  There were some films known for shifting colors a bit to the warm side, others the other way.  In any case, this only mattered for slide film which was used directly.  With negative film, the general color tone was a choice in printing.

Comment: I meant film as in movie stock. yes certain (still) films do push towards warm, that's what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most video footage is shot with a neutral white balance and then "graded" to taste in the editing suite.

Whilst you could use a warming filter on the lens it's much cheaper, easier and more flexible to shoot RAW and set a warm white balance when converting the images.

I did this in Adobe Camera RAW by warming the WB, adjusting the amount of green and applying a slight orange split tone to the highlights.

[image]

Comment: Im fairly sure this is more than just white balance at work tbh, i have tried to get this (or similar) look in the past - curves?

Comment: Could be slightly split-toned looks like there's more green in the shadows. There's a million different ways to manipulate the colours of an image, without seeing the original it's impossible to say.

Comment: thanks for adding the image - yes that's close, especially the sky blue.